# What can I use as a blank Request URL for Sms?

Tags: sms, twilio

In order for a number to receive Sms messages, it appears I must enter a value for the Request URL associated with the number. However I do not need to notified of messages in a callback. I'm wondering what value I can put in here that will basically do nothing but still allow me to retrieving messages via the polling mechanism?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can use a URL that responds with an empty `<Response>` TwiML element. If you don't have a server to host that on, you could use http://twimlets.com. This link ought to do the trick:

http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%3C%2FResponse%3E&